# Maping rows value in a dataframe to column values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

```
    Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
0   6.44   4.85   4.67   5.77
```

Dataframe df row values have to be mapped with
this

```
data=
[Timestamp('1996-03-31 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC') #This has to mapped with Q1
[Timestamp('1996-06-30 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC') #This with Q2
[Timestamp('1996-09-30 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC') #This with Q3
[Timestamp('1996-12-31 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC') #This with Q4
```

Comment: please show expected output

Comment: 1996-03-31  6.44                                                                                                     1996-06-30 4.85                                                                                                      
1996-09-30 4.67                                                                                                     1996-12-31 5.77